# Insertion sort not working, 32bit assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, insertion-sort

I'm trying to implement insertion sort in 32bit assembly in linux using NASM and I get a segmentation fault mid-run (not to mention that for some reason 'printf' prints random garbage values, I'm not totally sure why), Here is the 
code:
    section .rodata
    MSG:    DB  "welcome to sortMe, please sort me",10,0
    S1: DB  "%d",10,0 ; 10 = '\n' , 0 = '\0'

```
section .data

array   DD 5,1,7,3,4,9,12,8,10,2,6,11   ; unsorted array
len DB 12   

section .text
    align 16
    global main
    extern printf

main:
    push MSG    ; print welcome message
    call printf
    add esp,4   ; clean the stack 

    call printArray ;print the unsorted array

    ;parameters
    ;push len
    ;push array
    mov eax, len
    mov ebx, array
    push eax
    push ebx

    call myInsertionSort

    call printArray ; print the sorted one

    mov eax, 1  ;exit system call
    int 0x80

printArray:
    push ebp    ;save old frame pointer
    mov ebp,esp ;create new frame on stack
    pushad      ;save registers

    mov eax,0
    mov ebx,0
    mov edi,0

    mov esi,0   ;array index
    mov bl, byte [len]
    add edi,ebx ; edi = array size

print_loop:
    cmp esi,edi
    je print_end
    push dword [array+esi*4]
    push S1
    call printf
    add esp, 8  ;clean the stack
    inc esi
    jmp  print_loop
print_end:
    popa        ;restore registers
    mov esp,ebp ;clean the stack frame
    pop ebp     ;return to old stack frame
    ret

myInsertionSort:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]
    movzx ecx, byte [ecx]   ;put len in ecx, our loop variable
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov esi, [ebp+8] ; the array
    loop loop_1
    loop_1:
        cmp ecx, 0 ; if we're done
        je done_1 ; then done with loop
        mov edx, ecx
        push ecx ; we save len, because loop command decrements ecx
        sub edx, ecx
        mov ecx, [esi+4*edx] ;;;;;; ecx now array[i] ? how do I access array[i] in a similar manner?
        mov ebx, eax
        shr ebx, 2 ; number of times for inner loop
        loop_2:
            cmp ebx, 0 ; we don't use loop to not affect ecx so we use ebx and compare it manually with 0
            jl done_2
            cmp [esi+ebx], ecx ;we see if array[ebx] os ecx so we can exit the loop
            jle done_2
            lea edx, [esi+ebx]
            push dword [edx] ; pushing our array[ebx]
            add edx, 4
            pop dword [edx] ; popping the last one
            dec ebx ; decrementing the loop iterator
            jmp loop_2 ; looping again
        done_2:
            mov [esi+ebx+1], ecx
            inc eax ; incrementing iterator
            pop ecx ; len of array to compare now to eax and see if we're done
            jmp loop_1
    done_1:
        pop edi
        pop esi
        pop ebx
        pop ebp ; we pop them in opposite to how we pushed
        ret
```

About the printf thing, I'm positive that I should push the parameters the opposite way (first S1 and then the integer so it'd be from left to right as we'd call it in C), and if I do switch them, nothing is printed at all while I'm getting a segmentation fault. I don't know what to do, it prints these as output:

```
welcome to sortMe, please sort me
5
16777216
65536
256
1
117440512
458752
1792
7
50331648
196608
768
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mov ecx, [ebp+12]   ;put len in ecx, our loop variab
```

This only moves the address of LEN into ECX not its value!  You need to add `movzx ecx, byte [ecx]`

You also need to define LEN=48

```
loop loop_1
```

What's this bizare use of LOOP doing here?
You are mixing bytes and dwords on multiple occasions. You need to rework the code. p.e.

```
dec ebx ; ebx is now number of times we should go through inner loop
```

should become

```
shr ebx,2
```

This is not correct because you need the address and not the value. Change MOV into LEA.

```
jle done_2
mov edx, [esi+ebx]
```

Perhaps you can post your reworked code as an EDIT within your Original question.

Comment: Thank you, no core dumped, but it still doesn't actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Your edited code does not address ALL the problems signaled by user3144770!

The parameters to *printf* are correct but here are some additional problems with your *printArray* routine.

1. Since ESI is an index in an array of dwords you need to scale it up!

   push dword [array+esi*4]
2. Are you sure `pusha` will save 32 bits ? Perhaps you'd better use `pushad`

ps Should you decide to rework your code and post the edit then please **add the reworked code after the last line of the existing post**. This way the original question will continue making sense to people viewing it the first time!

Comment: Oh, thanks, still not working though, where can you see another problem ? I corrected what you noted. I am really upset, the assignment already expired but I want to learn from my mistakes anyway :P

Comment: I think it's because one of the line in the loops where I try to get array[i], I doubt I'm doing something alike to what I should do.